# how to query my data using multiple textboxes

Tags: sql, vb.net

i have textboxes called classno 1 to 8

i have a code like this:

```
Dim sqlQuery As String = "SELECT ClassNo, SubjectCode, Title, Lec, Lab, Days, 
TimeSlot, roomNo, Ins_ID 
from studSched WHERE SubjectCode = '" & classno1.Text & "' and '" & classno2.Text & "' and '" & classno3.Text & 
"' AND'" & classno4.Text & "' AND'" & classno5.Text & "' AND '" & classno6.Text & "' AND'" & classno7.Text & "' AND'" & classno8.Text & "' "
```

where textbox classno 1 to 8 have a value of subject 1 to 8

ex:
classno1="subject1"

how to query all textboxes in my access

my probelem is it will get all data in my access,
how to get all specific data in my access..

i need a code of my query..

Comment: Use parameterized queries to avoid SQL injection.

Comment: What 'specific data' do you want..?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need this

```
Dim sqlQuery As String = "SELECT ClassNo, SubjectCode, Title, Lec, 
                                 Lab, Days,TimeSlot, roomNo, Ins_ID 
                          FROM studSched 
                          WHERE SubjectCode = '" & classno1.Text & "' AND                    
                                SubjectCode = '" & classno2.Text & "' AND  
                                SubjectCode = '" & classno3.Text & "' AND  
                                SubjectCode = '" & classno4.Text & "' AND  
                                SubjectCode = '" & classno5.Text & "' AND  
                                SubjectCode = '" & classno6.Text & "' AND  
                                SubjectCode = '" & classno7.Text & "' AND  
                                SubjectCode = '" & classno8.Text & "' "
```

And this is not recommended, Use **Parameterized Query**

```
Dim Cmd as New SqlCommand()
cmd.Connection = con
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT ClassNo, SubjectCode, Title, Lec,Lab, Days,TimeSlot, roomNo,Ins_ID 
                   FROM studSched WHERE SubjectCode = @Sub1 AND SubjectCode = @Sub2 AND                     
                                        SubjectCode = @Sub3 AND SubjectCode = @Sub4 AND 
                                        SubjectCode = @Sub5 AND SubjectCode = @Sub6 AND        
                                        SubjectCode = @Sub7 AND SubjectCode = @Sub8"
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Sub1", classno1.Text)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Sub2", classno2.Text)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Sub3", classno3.Text)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Sub4", classno4.Text)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Sub5", classno5.Text)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Sub6", classno6.Text)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Sub7", classno7.Text)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Sub8", classno8.Text)
```

Comment: can u give me an example parameterized query